# JavaScript not Assigning to Global Variable

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, scope

I have the following code, which will return the login name for the currently logged-in SharePoint user :

```
var currentUser;
var currentUserName;
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(MainMethod,'sp.js');

function MainMethod() {
    GetName();
    alert("MAIN " + currentUserName);
}

function GetName(){
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
    currentUserName= currentUser.get_loginName().split("\\")[1];
    alert("GetName " + currentUserName);
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to retrieve user name');
}
```

When I run the code, I get these 2 alert message boxes :

`"GetName" firstname.lastname`

`"MAIN" undefined`

Shouldn't the line `currentUserName= currentUser.get_loginName().split("\\")[1];` assign the `firstname.lastname` value to the global `currentUserName` variable?

Comment: Have you checked the results of each part of that logic? i.e log out `currentUser.get_loginName()`, `currentUser.get_loginName().split("\\")` and `currentUser.get_loginName().split("\\")[1]`. Check they are all what you expect.

Comment: Yes they all return the correct values and the code works as expected apart from the variable assignment. `get_loginName()` returns the users' name in the form `i:0#.w|domain\firstname.lastname`

Comment: try assigning value to window.currentUserName

Comment: @meen I have tried that but without any success - I still just get `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `alert("MAIN " + currentUserName);` in `success()` function. It will get the changed value, but not in `MainMethod()` because jsom executing asynchroneously.

- It will first execute `GetName()` function
- Then it will execute the `alert("MAIN " + currentUserName);`
- Then it will execute `onQuerySucceeded()`

That's why you are getting undefined for MAIN because MAIN is executing before the `success()`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation Ronak that is very helpful - I guess I need to find a way of executing the method synchronously!

Answer (score 3):

You can make sure that you're accesing global property by using `window.currentUserName = currentUser.get_loginName().split("\\")[1]`.

To avoid polluting global namespace with many variables you can group them in an object like this:

```
window.user = {
    currentUserName,
    currentUser
}
```

Then you could access it by `window.user.currentUserName`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in this case - I still get the `undefined` variable message